# How to use connected-react-router's push within unit tests

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, jestjs, connected-react-router

I want to update the URL that is stored in my `redux` store by `connected-react-router` during testing, because some of my logic depends on that. When I `dispatch` a `push`, the actions gets logged (I was able to verify that using a logger middleware), but the actual state does not change.

I have this code to reproduce the specific issue:

```js
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { connectRouter, push, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';


const history = createMemoryHistory();


export function createReduxStore() {
    return createStore(
        combineReducers({
            router: connectRouter(history),
        }),
        {},
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(
                routerMiddleware(history),
                thunkMiddleware,
            )
        )
    );
}


describe('router', () => {
    it('gets the correct data in URL', () => {
        const store = createReduxStore();
        expect(store.getState().router.location.pathname).toEqual('/');

        store.dispatch(push('/kg/firefox/resource/?string=42'));
        // This fails, `pathname` is still "/"
        expect(store.getState().router.location.pathname).toEqual('/kg/firefox/resource/');
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working as I expect it to?

Relevant packages:

```
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "connected-react-router": "6.8.0",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in connected-react-router tests :
https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/test/ConnectedRouter.test.js

the component ConnectedRouter subscribe to the store when he's mounted :
https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/src/ConnectedRouter.js

You need to mount the component with enzime as they do in their tests

```
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

beforeEach(() => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const store = createReduxStore(history);


    //init connected-react-router to connect history and store
     mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <Route path="/" render={() => <div>Test</div>} />
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
      );
  });
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a link to details about the solution.